# ZKEMKeeper not disabling user

Tags: zkemkeeper

I am using ESSL MB 160 whichuses zkemkeeper. It works fine for retrieving data but when i am disabling user it says success but not disabling. Device has admins? Can't i disable the normal user from s/w if there is any admins or any other issue

```
objZkeeper.SSR_EnableUser(1, EnrollNumber, false);
objZkeeper.EnableUser(1,EnrollNumber, 1,0,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the essl biometric devices do support enabling/disabling the user. But SDK has operation for doing it so. It is strange, but truth is, hardware doesnt support.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry replying bit late as Covid no work :) Did you ever tried with Zkem SDK to disable the user?

Comment: Yes, we have, but , it never worked ! :-)